# Django detailview filter by other fields like isbn

Tags: python, django, detailview

If I have another field like ISBN in book so how do I filter with this field in from *django.views.generic import DetailField*

here is my book/urls.py file code

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',BookListView.as_view(), name="book_list"),
    path('<isbn>/',BookDetailView.as_view(), name="book_detail")
]
```

book/views.py

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = "book/detail.html"
    def get_queryset(self,*args, **kwargs):
        print(self.kwargs['isbn'])
        return BookModel.objects.filter(isbn=self.kwargs['isbn'])
```

and the Error is

> Generic detail view BookDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Answer (score 1):

you can use isbn as slug

book/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',BookListView.as_view(), name="book_list"),
    path('<slug:isbn>/',BookDetailView.as_view(), name="book_detail")
]
```

book/views.py

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = BookModel
    template_name = "book/detail.html"
    slug_field = 'isbn'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'isbn'
```